# Web API 2 deserialise object which contains Dictionary<string, dynamic>

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API2 post action which accepts a JObject.

```
    [Route("api/Sendemail")]
    public void Post([FromBody]JObject value)
    {
        var personalisation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(value.First.ToString());
        var recipientEmail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(value.GetValue("Email").ToString());
        var templateId = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(value.GetValue("TemplateId").ToString());

        var response = _client.SendEmail(recipientEmail, templateId, personalisation);
    }
```

I'm passing into this from my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(FeedbackForm model)
    {
        //Send feedback to address

        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        try
        {
            var personalisation = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>
            {
                {"feedback",model.Feedback},
                {"name",model.Name},
                {"email",model.Email},
                {"response",""},
                {"referrer",model.Referrer}
            };

            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Personalisation", personalisation.ToString()),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Email", "someone@example.com"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("TemplateId", "blah")
            });

            //Sending POST 
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/api/sendemail", formContent);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Thanks");
    }
```

The request looks to be going over correctly but I cant seem to deserialise it correctly, specifically the Dictionary object. The Email and TemplateId are being retrieved correctly.

I think I might have to have a strongly typed object for the post request?

Comment: The output of `personalisation.ToString()` is not what you think. Try it out and see what it is in a simple console app. Do a quick test.

Comment: I'm not sure if `dyncamic` is necessary here -- I'd avoid it if possible, since it probably makes serialization reflection impossible, since the serializer can't use reflection anymore, to find out how it should serialize the property -- is this demanded by your Web API Framework, or did you choose this yourself?

Comment: @phi1010 yes the dynamic property of the Dictionary is set by the provider of the service I have no control over it.

Comment: The provider of the service shouldn't be able to determine this type, only the provider of the library which provides the JObject.  Maybe use something like `class Personalization{string feedback{get;set;} int customer{get;set;}}` instead, if this is possible?